# Force Grafana Agent to use IPv4 for scraping Prometheus data from Spring Boot application

Tags: ubuntu, grafana

Is there a way to force the Grafana Agent to use IPv4 when  scraping Prometheus data from a Spring Boot application? In the Tomcat access logs of the application, I'm seeing that the Grafana Agent request comes from `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` instead of the expected and authorized `127.0.0.1`:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [14/Aug/2022:18:48:44 +0000] "GET /api/actuator/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 403 123
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer by myself. In the `grafana-agent.yaml` configuration file, in the `targets` section, use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`:

```
metrics:
...
    - job_name: integrations/spring-boot
      metrics_path: /api/actuator/prometheus
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 127.0.0.1:8082
  global:
    scrape_interval: 60s
  wal_directory: /tmp/grafana-agent-wal
```